# split array into multiple rows in hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table with one of the example row:

```
LX556, 22, [“11”, “12”, “13”], [“FL”, “CA”, “TX”]
```

the length of array in column 3 and 4 will be the same! I want to break the array and create new rows.

Output:

```
LX556, 22, 11, FL. 
LX556, 22, 12, CA. 
LX556, 22, 13, TX.
```

I am new to hive and really need help figuring this out.

The length of arrays keeps changing. It’s not static. sometimes it’s of length 3 or 4 or 5. That’s where i’m stuck.

Comment: `LX556, 22, [“11”, “12”, “13”], [“FL”, “CA”, “TX”]` is that "one" string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to use [posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode).

```sql
with sample_table as (
  select 'LX556' col1, 22 col2, array('11', '12', '13') arr1, array('FL', 'CA', 'TX') arr2
)
 select col1, col2, val1, val2 
   from sample_table t 
lateral view posexplode(arr1) tf1 as pos1,val1 
lateral view posexplode(arr2) tf2 as pos2,val2
  where pos1 = pos2
```

**Query results**

[image]